# How to pass a variable number of arguments to sscanf?

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I need to call the following function in my code that can be used to extract integers from a specified string format:

```
int sscanf(const char *str, const char *format, ...)
```

I need to be able to pass in a period-delimited string of numbers (i.e. 1.20.3.4) to the function, so my format string will be in the form `%d.%d.%d.%d`.

The issue is, the numbers I pass to the function during runtime will have a random amount of numbers separated by periods. In other words, on one call I may pass `1.23`, but on the next call I may pass `1.23.45.6`. Generating the format string on the fly is an easy task, however I am unsure of whether it's possible to pass in a variable number of remaining arguments that are used to store the results of the function.

Does anyone know if this is possible or have any other ideas?

Comment: You can't do it with `sscanf()`. Use a `strtok()` loop to parse it.

Comment: Did you consider using sscanf in a loop?

Comment: As @Yunnosch notes, you can loop with `sscanf`. That said @Barmar's suggestion to use `strtok` (or `strtok_r` if available) is probably the best solution here.

Answer (score 0):

If you know there is an upper limit on the count of integers then just always `sscanf()` for that many arguments.  The return value from `sscanf()` will tell you the count that were successfully scanned, which means you don't need to procedurally generate the format string.

Answer (score 0):

How about using MACRO?

Define a `MACRO` like:

```
#define your_func(str, format, args...) \
    // do your own job \
    sscanf(str, format, ##args); \
    // do your own joy
```

Then just use it like a `FUNCTION`:

```
your_func("1.2", "%d.%d", &a, &b);
your_func("1.2.3", "%d.%d.%d", &a, &b, &c);
```